# Encrypting two messages with the same content with different keys/IVs still secure if attacker knows they are the same?

Tags: aes, symmetric, attack, chacha, serpent

I want **to store two ciphertexts inside the same file**.
The data stored in each ciphertext is the same (except for padding), but the data was encrypted **with different keys and IVs**. Both ciphertexts were also generated by the same algorithm.

In this case specifically that would be a variant of AES, Chacha20 or Serpent.

In my scenario the attacker would **know only** that both ciphertexts hold **the same data** and the original **data's length/size** (with and without the padding) and then ofc also the **padding's size**.

He does not know what the plaintext/data looks like and he also does not know what the padding looks like.

Does this reduce the amount of power/time needed to crack the ciphertext? Are different keys +IVs and also different padding **values**/**bytes** (*not length*) enough to keep the data secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be secure as long as each algorithm is CPA-secure (as AES, Chacha20 and Serpent should be), and the keys are chosen independently and uniformly at random (different keys is not enough).

> Does this reduce the amount of power/time needed to crack the ciphertext?

No compared to attacking the easier to attack of the two algorithms, assuming ability to recognize a correct plaintext (e.g. because it's quite redundant). In theory, for random unknown plaintext, it becomes possible to verify a correct guess of both keys, but that's not a practical issue.

I don't see much value in using different IVs and padding. IVs are here to allow key reuse, and repel multi-target attacks.